# Can any one tell me how to find the records not in second table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to find the records which are present in the second from the first table in sql server 2005.

Comment: What is your table structure? what are the columns that link the two tables? what have you tried? Do you know what a join is?

Comment: i know join.I tried alot .OK.If u have any solution just give or else leave it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/).

This is a very good article with graphical explanations of what the various joins are used for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Table1 T1
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
          Table2 T2
      WHERE
          T2.CommonColumn = T1.CommonColumn)
```